# How to show an image in the mobile application

Tags: acumatica

I have a request to add the image from a stock item to the picking screen in the mobile app in Acumatica.  I took a look at the Mobile Framework documentation but, there doesn't appear to be a way to show an image in the mobile app.  Has anybody tried something like this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a control for ImageURL in the mobile app as of now.

However, as long as your screen holds a Header record with Files(attachments) you could still see the attachments(images) in the mobile application.

For this you can take as an example and guidance the EP301020 - Expense Receipt screen:

```
add screen EP301020 {
  openAs = Form
  add container "ClaimDetails" {
    formActionsToExpand = 1
    add layout "ReceiptNumberHeader" {
      displayName = "ReceiptNumberHeader"
      layout = "HeaderFirstAttachment"
      add field "ReceiptNumber" {
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
      add field "Status" {
        forceIsDisabled = True
      }
    }
    add field "DetailsExpenseDetails#Description"
    .....................
    attachments {
      imageAdjustmentPreset = Receipt
    }
  }
...............
}
```

See more details about the layout "HeaderFirstAttachment" here:
https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bd31e3a8-538f-47d5-84ff-251ca3d03c43